# Angular Resource with Hateoas and application/hal+json

Tags: angularjs, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I have this kind of response format from backend (URL is http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency ):

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "code": "CHF",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/CHF"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "EUR",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/EUR"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "USD",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/USD"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "AUD",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/AUD"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "CAD",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/CAD"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "GBP",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/GBP"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "NZD",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/NZD"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "JPY",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/JPY"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "SEK",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/SEK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "NOK",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/NOK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "ISK",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/ISK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "code": "DKK",
      "_links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency/DKK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "_links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/App/api/currency"
    }
  ]
}
```

To query it with Angular I use `$resource's` query method. But this response structure does not work well with `$resource`:

- query expects array. Here I have single object
- array items are treated as single resources

How can I make this response work with `$resource` i.e. instruct it to take `content` as actual data for constructing `$resource` objects. Or are there any robust solutions for it?

Comment: You can add a response transformer. The response isn't  really `hal+json` BTW. The configuration is probably missing something.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `$promise` explicitly:

```
return $resource(url).get().$promise.then(function(response){
    return response.content;
});
```

Of course, when using `$resource` this way, there's not much difference with `$http`, and the advantages of using `$resource` over `$http`, like directly binding the result to the scope, are lost.

Comment: I think you missed my point: I don't $resource's client code to do it manually + i does not resolve "array items are treated as single resources" issue